# Objective C setting labels after api call

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, asynchronous

UPDATE

I am making an api call getPacks() and successfully getting the values of two variables _numberOfPacks and _numberOfAutoRefills.

However, when I try to put it in a label it fails and gives output as (null) Packs & (null) Autorefiils

the calls are made in the following order:

1. getpacks()-------first (it sets value on _numberOfPacks and _numberOfAutoRefills as global variables
2. drawQuantity()-----set _numberOfPacks and _numberOfAutoRefills on labels.

```
-(void) getPacks: (IHPlacedOrder*)order{

NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://XXXXXXX.XXXXX/%@",order.ID]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                     initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if([string isEqualToString:@""]){

    } else {

        NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSLog(@"%@",dict);

        _numberOfPacks = [[dict objectForKey:@"prescription_interval"] valueForKey:@"quantity_per_interval"];
        _numberOfAutoRefills = [[dict objectForKey:@"prescription_interval"]valueForKey:@"num_intervals"];

        NSLog(@"PACKS:%@ , AUTOREFILLS:%@",_numberOfPacks,_numberOfAutoRefills);

        _quantity.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@,%@",_numberOfPacks,_numberOfAutoRefills];

    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%s: AFHTTPRequestOperation error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}];

[networkQueue addOperation:operation];
```

}

followed by:

```
-(void)drawQuantity: (IHPlacedOrder*)order{

    PPLinearLayoutLabelItem *quantityLabel = [[PPLinearLayoutLabelItem alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ QUANTITY & %@ REFILLS", _numberOfPacks,_numberOfAutoRefills] font:[PPFonts regular18] maxWidth:[LayoutValues getMaxWidthClipped]];
    [quantityLabel setPaddingBottom:5];
    [quantityLabel setPaddingTop:20];
    [self.topContainerContent addObject:quantityLabel];

    NSString* quantityText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Packs + Autorefills"];


    PPLinearLayoutLabelItem *quantity = [[PPLinearLayoutLabelItem alloc] initWithText:quantityText font:[PPFonts genericParagraphFontBold] maxWidth:[LayoutValues getMaxWidthClipped]];
    [quantity setPaddingBottom:20];
    [self.topContainerContent addObject:quantity];

    LinearLayoutHorizontalLine *line1 = [[LinearLayoutHorizontalLine alloc] initWithMaxWidth:[LayoutValues getMaxWidthClipped]];
    [self.topContainerContent addObject:line1];
}
```

Comment: Is the log of `PACKS` and `AUTOREFILLS` showing the right value? If so, you should just trigger the update the UI in the completion handler, like Paul said.

Comment: Unrelated, but once you get this issue behind you, I'm not sure why you're taking the data, converting it to a string, and then converting it back to a data, in order to call `NSJSONSerialization`. Just use the `responseObject`. Or, even better, if you use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, it will do the parsing for you. Also, BTW, I assume you know that you shouldn't be using this request operation implementation anymore, as it is `NSURLConnection`-based, and that's now deprecated...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the _quantity.text = line and check two things: _quantity is not nil, and you are on the main thread. If either of those things is false, your UI update will fail.

Comment: You aren't saving your labels - you want `self.quantity = [[PPLinearLayoutLabelItem alloc] initWithText:quantityText font:[PPFonts genericParagraphFontBold] maxWidth:[LayoutValues getMaxWidthClipped]];`.  Don't use _ to bypass the setter/getter unless you know why you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was using wrong method call to set labels. The thing is my application uses PPLinearLayoutLabelItem as a custom built label. I had to call [self.quantity setLabel:@"%@",data_fromapi] to make it work. setText would just set the text within PPLinearLayoutLabelItem class and not set the Label.